# In Fusion Tables and Google Maps API, how do I change the Tables layer and the Map position based on dropdown menu selection?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to make a site which uses different Fusion Tables. There is a dropdown menu which has several states. Each state has its own Fusion Table

I would like to make it so that when you pick a state, the map loads up that state' Fusion Table.

How do I do that?

Below is my JavaScript code so far (filename is 'script.js'). Below that is the HTML code.

When I change the state via dropdown, I'd like the map to load up the Fusion Table map of the state in the dropdown. Right now, it does not do that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var states = {
        'Alabama':'3348442',
        'Alaska':'3370522'
    };
    // SECTION 1: ADDING HTML TO DOM
    var bodyDivs = [
        '<div id="map-canvas" />',
        '<div id="address-form-container" />',
        '<div id="state-select-container"><select id="state-select" /></div>'
    ];

    var addressContainer = [
        '<span id="form pretext"> Enter a city name or address </span>',
        '<input id="address" type="textbox" />',
        '<input type="button" value="Search" />'
    ];

    // Append the body to <html>
    $('html').append('<body />');
    for (var i=0; i<bodyDivs.length; i++){
        $('body').append(bodyDivs[i]);
    };

    // Append the address form to <body>
    for (var i=0; i<addressContainer.length; i++){
        $('div#address-form-container').append(addressContainer[i]);
    };

    // Append state names to the body
    for (var state in states){
        $('select').append('<option value='+state+'>'+state+'</option>');
    };
    // DONE ADDING HTML TO DOM


    // SECTION 2: Create the Google map with the coordinates and add the Fusion Tables layer to it. Plus, it zooms and centers to whatever state is selected.
    var geocoder;
    var gmap;
    var locationColumn = "'geometry'";
    var condition = "'Median income (dollars)'>0";
    var selectedState = document.getElementById("state-select").value;
    var tableId = states[selectedState];    
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    function initialize(){
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // This variables is used to automate zooming and centering in this script
        gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions); // Removing this removes the Google Maps layer, but would keep any layers on top of it

        // The Fusion Tables layer variable
        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: locationColumn,
                from: tableId,
                where: condition
            }
        });

        // This code snippet centers and zooms the map to the selected state.
        geocoder.geocode(
            {
                'address':selectedState
            },
            function(results,status){
                var sw = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();
                var ne = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw,ne);

                gmap.fitBounds(bounds)
            }
        );

        layer.setMap(gmap);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(selectedState,'change',function(){
            updateMap(layer,tableId,locationColumn);
        });         
    }


    // SECTION 3: Find the address once the button is clicked
    $(':button').click(
        function codeAddress(){
            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

            geocoder.geocode(
                {
                    'address':address
                },
                function(results,status){
                    if(status===google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                        var addressSW = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();
                        var addressNE = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
                        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(addressSW,addressNE);

                        gmap.fitBounds(bounds);
                    } else {
                        alert("Couldn't find address for the following reason: " + status + ". Sorry about that. Please try another address.");
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );


    function updateMap(layer,tableId,locationColumn){
        if (selectedState) {
            tableId = states[selectedState];

            layer.setOptions({
                query: {
                    select: locationColumn,
                    from: tableId,
                    where: condition
                }
            });

            geocoder.geocode(
                {
                    'address':selectedState
                },
                function(results,status){
                    var sw = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();
                    var ne = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw,ne);

                    gmap.fitBounds(bounds)
                }
            );          
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

CSS:

```
#map-canvas {
height: 800px;
width: 1000px;
```

}

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>TESTING THE MAPS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

EDIT: Links to the HTML, CSS, and JS files---
http://speedy.sh/xRkZF/maptest.html
http://speedy.sh/zSt5p/script.js
http://speedy.sh/uCPxZ/style.css

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: When I change the state via dropdown, I'd like the map to load up the Fusion Table map of the state in the dropdown. Right now, it does not do that.

Comment: What does it do? Any errors?

Comment: Nah, there are no errors. If you open the page, the Alabama table loads, but if you select another state from the dropdown, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you provide a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Sure, I haven't put it online yet, so here is a .rar file containing the HTML, JS, and CSS files. http://speedy.sh/QYPk5/stackoverflow-help.zip. (I just noticed I forgot to include the CSS code in my question, so I updated it accordingly.

Comment: I don't currently have anything that will extract the files from that

Comment: Edited my post to include links to the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hardcoded selectedState, but you need to get the current value when the dropdown changes.

Modify the change-listener to this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('state-select'),
  'change',
  function(){
        updateMap(layer,this.value,locationColumn);
    });
```

Now the 2nd argument passed to updateMap will be the selected state from the dropdown.
Also modify updateMap, change the name of the 2nd argument to selectedState:

function updateMap(layer,**selectedState**,locationColumn){
  //function code may stay as it is
  }

Everything should work fine now.

Comment: Thanks, @Dr Molle. This works, though I wonder why it does. I guess I'm just unfamiliar with what each of '.addDomListener's' arguments are (and I don't think the Fusion Tables API Reference doc helped much). Also, I wonder what each argument in 'updateMap' means, and why it's needed in the first place.